# How do I use bssrdf_gaussian and bssrdf_cubic in OSL?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, osl

I'm repeatedly getting errors reported that these functions are not defined, but they are explicitly mentioned [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/osl.html) in the documentation. Everything else on this page has worked so far, including `henyey_greenstein`; but not the two bssrdf functions.

I've included stdosl.h (just in case), I've used an assortment of different parameters and parameter types, but it never seems to recognize it. Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Comment: can u post a script that is supposed to work? are you on Blender 3.6?

Comment: I think it might be out of date docs? Cubic and Gaussian were options on the Cycles SSS shader node menu at one point, and now are not. Idk if the BSSRDF code is still in the engine, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's not and nobody updated that page for what the new BSSDRF names were. See https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#Removed_Features_and_Compatibility

Comment: @JtheNinja I think you might be right; I'm not too-good to do some source code digging, and will double check. This may be a simple documentation bug that needs reporting, I just thought I would check.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie There's really not much more to show, it just doesn't recognize the function.